# Reference list item as key in sorted for loop

Tags: python, list, sorting

Sorry for boring question but I can't figure this out:

```
for f in sorted(os.listdir('.')): print f
```

Output:

```
p1.html
p10.html
p11.html
p12.html
p13.html
p14.html
p15.html
p16.html
p17.html
p18.html
p19.html
p2.html
p20.html
p21.html
p22.html
p3.html
p4.html
...
```

Obviously I want to sort by number and I can do it with this key: `f.split('.')[0][1:]` but how to reference that key in this for loop?

I tried `for f in sorted(os.listdir('.'), key=f.split('.')[0][1:])` but it does not work of course

TIA

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort

Comment: I don't want to import re module

Comment: @otrov: Any rational reason for that?

Comment: why should I load it when I don't need it?

Comment: @otrov, its there to make your life easy. Not wanting to load it is silly.

Comment: @Winston Ewert: Well, as you can see from the provided answer it would be overkill to do so. Yeah, I could have solved it with couple of extra lines myself, but then I wouldn't go here and ask for help. BTW re module is one of my favorites regularly, but not here

Comment: @otrov, ok. Just as long as you don't have a silly superstition about loading the module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need a lambda expression:

```
sorted(os.listdir('.'), key=lambda f: int(f.split('.')[0][1:]))
```

Comment: He's probably looking for a numerical sort... so IMO it should be `lambda f:int(f.split('.')[0][1:])`